# Cell are created but not shown in UITableView

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uitableview, uisearchbar

that's my first question here.

My UITableView doesn't show all cells that are created. What's the problem?

After App is launched it downloads data from server and shows it using UITableView. When i'm scrolling UITableView my app downloads more data (like Twitter app). And everything shows just fine.

But I also have a UISearchBar. And there's a problem. When SearchBar is active everything works just the same way (e.g. it downloads first part of data when I'm typing and downloads another when i'm scrolling), but UITableView shows only first part of data.

But NSLog in cellForRowAtIndexPath tells me, that ALL cell are created just fine. And I don't know what to do with it.

Sorry for my English, it's not so good.

Also, numberOfRowsInSection return the right value (e.g. 3), while there are only 1 cell in UITableView is shown. And, of course, my arrays contain all data i need to show.

```
    - (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
    {
        return 1;
    }

    - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
    {
        if(searching == 0){ //if we aren't in search
            NSLog(@"Total rows %d", ids.count);
            return [ids count];
        }
        if(searching == 1){ //if we are in search
            NSLog(@"Total rows %d", idsSearch.count);
            return [idsSearch count];
        }
    }

    - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
        static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

        UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        if (cell == nil) {
            cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
            if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) {
                cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
            }
        }

        NSInteger row = [indexPath row];

        if(searching == 0){
            cell.textLabel.text = [names objectAtIndex:row];
            NSLog(@"Cell with %@ created", [names objectAtIndex:row]);
        }

        if(searching == 1){
            cell.textLabel.text = [namesSearch objectAtIndex:row];
            NSLog(@"Cell with %@ created", [namesSearch objectAtIndex:row]); //tells me that ALL cells were created. But they aren't in UITableView.
        }

        return cell;
    }

    - (void)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar textDidChange:(NSString *)searchText {
        searchRequest = searchBar.text;
        if([searchRequest isEqualToString:@""]){
            searching = 0;
        }
        else{
            searching = 1;

            [idsSearch removeAllObjects];
            [namesSearch removeAllObjects];

            [self getArtistsStartFrom:0 withLimit:1]; //downloads new data (1 record in this example) with needed predicate (searchRequest) from server, then adds it to arrays and performs [self.tableView reloadData] at the end.
        }
    }
```

Comment: in testDidChange, have you tried doing [self.tableView reloadData]?